# in iOS Entended Audio File Services and Streaming Audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

First Export from iPod Library m4a file.
Second Convert to AAC using Extended Audio File Services
Third transport the music file to other iPhone.
Fourth Streaming audio using Audio File Stream Services
It usually works.But the audio file playtime over about 5minitues it can't work.
However,I try 15minitues audio file mp3 and aac into my project.and streaming it.it worked.
So,I think the cause is Convert Step. Something wrong with my code ?
Could you give me some advices ?

```
-(void)convertFrom:(NSURL*)fromURL
         toURL:(NSURL*)toURL{
ExtAudioFileRef infile,outfile;
OSStatus err;
//ExtAudioFileの作成
err = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fromURL, &infile);
checkError(err,"ExtAudioFileOpenURL");

AudioStreamBasicDescription inputFormat;
AudioStreamBasicDescription outputFormat;
AVAudioSession * audiosession =[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audiosession setActive:YES error:nil];
[audiosession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing error:nil];

//変換するフォーマット(AAC)
memset(&outputFormat, 0, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
outputFormat.mSampleRate       = 44100.0;
outputFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;//AAC
outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;

UInt32 size = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo,
                       0, NULL,
                       &size,
                       &outputFormat);//変換後のフォーマット


err = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(infile,//変換前のファイルのプロパティを取得
                              kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat,
                              &size,
                              &inputFormat);
checkError(err,"ExtAudioFileGetProperty");

//リニアPCM以外からの変換であれば、リニアPCMとして読み込む
if(inputFormat.mFormatID != kAudioFormatLinearPCM){
    //一旦変換するフォーマット(リニアPCM Little Endian)
    AudioStreamBasicDescription linearPCMFormat;
    linearPCMFormat.mSampleRate         = outputFormat.mSampleRate;
    linearPCMFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    linearPCMFormat.mFormatFlags        =  kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
    linearPCMFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    linearPCMFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    linearPCMFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    linearPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2 * outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    linearPCMFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2 * outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    linearPCMFormat.mReserved           = 0;

    //読み出すフォーマットをリニアPCMにする(中間フォーマット)
    inputFormat = linearPCMFormat;
}
//読み込むフォーマットを設定
//必ずlinearPCMで読み出される
err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(infile,
                              kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                              sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription),
                              &inputFormat);
checkError(err,"ExtAudioFileSetProperty");



err = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)toURL,
                                kAudioFileM4AType, //AAC
                                &outputFormat,
                                NULL,
                                kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                &outfile);
checkError(err,"ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL");

//書き込むファイルに、入力がリニアPCMであることを設定
err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(outfile,
                              kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                              sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription),
                              &inputFormat);
checkError(err,"kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat");

//読み込み位置を0に移動
err = ExtAudioFileSeek(infile, 0);
checkError(err,"ExtAudioFileSeek");

//一度に読み込むフレーム数
UInt32 readFrameSize = 1024;

//読み込むバッファ領域を確保
UInt32 bufferByteSize = sizeof(char) * readFrameSize * inputFormat.mBytesPerPacket;
char *buffer = malloc(bufferByteSize);

//AudioBufferListの作成
AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = bufferByteSize;
audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = buffer;

while(1){
    UInt32 numPacketToRead = readFrameSize;
    err = ExtAudioFileRead(infile, &numPacketToRead, &audioBufferList);
    checkError(err,"ExtAudioFileRead");

    //読み込むフレームが無くなったら終了する
    if(numPacketToRead == 0){
        NSLog(@"変換完了");
        break;

    }
    err = ExtAudioFileWrite(outfile,
                            numPacketToRead,
                            &audioBufferList);
    checkError(err,"ExtAudioFileWrite");
}

ExtAudioFileDispose(infile);
ExtAudioFileDispose(outfile);
free(buffer);
void propertyListenerProc(
                      void *                            inClientData,
                      AudioFileStreamID             inAudioFileStream,
                      AudioFileStreamPropertyID     inPropertyID,
                      UInt32 *                      ioFlags
                      ){

StreamInfo* streamInfo = (StreamInfo*)inClientData;
OSStatus err;
NSLog(@"property%u",(unsigned int)inPropertyID);
```

Comment: do any of your calls to `checkError` display any errors?

Comment: There is no error. But  in bad case, audio file stream callback function ,propatylisner called only one time.

Comment: Oh, so is it only one file (the "5 minute one") that does not work?  Besides the length of time, what are the other differences between the 5 minute file and the 15 minute audio file?

Comment: I prepared the 15minitues file using iTunes encoder.So,different between two file is conversion environment usually streaming services property callback get some property like this       property1717988724
property1835493731
property1718383476
property1650683508
property1885564532
property1886616165
property1685022310
property1886283375
property1919247481

Comment: in long music file (Convert in iPhone)only shows this property1717988724

Comment: Could you prepare (or convert) your 5 minute audio file the same way, via the iTunes Encoder, just to see if the same problem still exists?  Also, which "property" are you talking about?  input or output format?

Comment: I prepare the audio file two way. one is convert in iPhone program,another is convert in Mac iTunes they are same format AAC ,Result is success in later one(iTunes one). And I said property .It is stream services log,in the stream services callback function I"ll add some code

Comment: propertyListenerProc is callback function when stream services receive audio header(property)

Comment: Thank you . I changed Format IMA-4 it is worked in long file. I will use it.